# call a Python function from c++ using pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am trying to call a python function from a C++ code which contains `main()` function using `Pybind11`. But I found very few references are available. Most of existing documents talk about the reversed direction, i.e. calling C++ from Python.

Is there any complete example showing how to do that? The only reference I found is: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/30

But it has very little information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. project structure

- CMakeLists.txt
- calc.py
- main.cpp

2. main.cpp

   ```cpp
   #include <pybind11/embed.h>
   #include <iostream>
   namespace py = pybind11;
   using namespace py::literals;


   int main() {
       py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

       // append source dir to sys.path, and python interpreter would find your custom python file
       py::module_ sys = py::module_::import("sys");
       py::list path = sys.attr("path");
       path.attr("append")("..");

       // import custom python class and call it
       py::module_ tokenize = py::module_::import("calc");
       py::type customTokenizerClass = tokenize.attr("CustomTokenizer");
       py::object customTokenizer = customTokenizerClass("/Users/Caleb/Desktop/codes/ptms/bert-base");
       py::object res = customTokenizer.attr("custom_tokenize")("good luck");

       // show the result
       py::list input_ids = res.attr("input_ids");
       py::list token_type_ids = res.attr("token_type_ids");
       py::list attention_mask = res.attr("attention_mask");
       py::list offsets = res.attr("offset_mapping");
       std::string message = "input ids is {},\noffsets is {}"_s.format(input_ids, offsets);
       std::cout << message << std::endl;
   }
   ```
3. calc.py

   ```py
   from transformers import BertTokenizerFast


   class CustomTokenizer(object):
       def __init__(self, vocab_dir):
           self._tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(vocab_dir)

       def custom_tokenize(self, text):
           return self._tokenizer(text, return_offsets_mapping=True)


   def build_tokenizer(vocab_dir: str) -> BertTokenizerFast:
       tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(vocab_dir)
       return tokenizer


   def tokenize_text(tokenizer: BertTokenizerFast, text: str) -> dict:
       res = tokenizer(text, return_offsets_mapping=True)
       return dict(res)
   ```
4. CMakeLists.txt

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
   project(example)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

   # set pybind11 dir
   set(pybind11_DIR /Users/Caleb/Softwares/pybind11)
   find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

   # set custom python interpreter(under macos)
   link_libraries(/Users/Caleb/miniforge3/envs/py38/lib/libpython3.8.dylib)

   add_executable(example main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
   ```

Comment: An exception is throwing in line `py::module_ tokenize = py::module_::import("calc");`

Comment: `transformers` package is needed.

Answer (score 28):

The answer to your question really has two parts: one about calling a Python function from C++, the other about embedding the interpreter.

Calling a function in pybind11 is simply a matter of getting that function into a `pybind11::object` variable, on which you can invoke `operator()` to attempt to call the object.  (It doesn't have to be a function, but just something callable: for example, it could also be an object with a `__call__` method).  For example, to call `math.sqrt(2)` from C++ code you'd use:

```
auto math = py::module::import("math");
auto resultobj = math.attr("sqrt")(2);
double result = resultobj.cast<double>();
```

or you could condense it all to just:

```
double result = py::module::import("math").attr("sqrt")(2).cast<double>();
```

The second part of the question involves how to do this from a C++ executable.  When building an executable (i.e. when your C++ code contains `main()`) you have to embed the Python interpreter in your binary before you can do anything with Python (like calling a Python function).

Embedded support is a new feature added in the current pybind11 `master` branch (which will become the 2.2 release).  Here's a basic example that starts an embedded Python interpreter and calls a Python function (`math.sqrt`):

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter python;

    auto math = py::module::import("math");
    double root_two = math.attr("sqrt")(2.0).cast<double>();

    std::cout << "The square root of 2 is: " << root_two << "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
The square root of 2 is: 1.41421
```

More examples and documentation of calling functions and embedding are available at http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html and http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html, respectively.

Comment: The links above are broken. Use the one below:
- https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

Answer (score 20):

Jasons answer is pretty much on point, but I want to add a slightly more complex (and clean) example calling a python method with a `numpy` input.
I want to showcase two points:

1. We can cast a `py::object` to a `py::function` using `py::reinterpret_borrow<py::function>`
2. We can input a `std::vector` that automatically gets converted to a `numpy.array`

Note that the user is responsible for making sure that the `PyModule.attr` is actually a python function. Also note that the type conversion works for a wide variety of `c++` types (see [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/cast/stl.html) for details).

In this example I want to use the method `scipy.optimize.minimize` with a starting point `x0` that is provided from the c++ interface.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>  // python interpreter
#include <pybind11/stl.h>  // type conversion

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
  std::cout << "Starting pybind" << std::endl;
  py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start interpreter, dies when out of scope

  py::function min_rosen =
      py::reinterpret_borrow<py::function>(   // cast from 'object' to 'function - use `borrow` (copy) or `steal` (move)
          py::module::import("py_src.exec_numpy").attr("min_rosen")  // import method "min_rosen" from python "module"
      );

  py::object result = min_rosen(std::vector<double>{1,2,3,4,5});  // automatic conversion from `std::vector` to `numpy.array`, imported in `pybind11/stl.h`
  bool success = result.attr("success").cast<bool>();
  int num_iters = result.attr("nit").cast<int>();
  double obj_value = result.attr("fun").cast<double>();
}
```

with the python script `py_src/exec_numpy.py`

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen, rosen_der

def min_rosen(x0):
    res = minimize(rosen, x0)
    return res
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hi , I am trying to use your code but I get i am getting an expetion : Microsoft C++ exception: pybind11::error_already_set at memory

Comment: The last three lines of the C++ code have `res.attr` but these should be `result.attr`.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid copying the data from the STL container into a `numpy.array` during the automatic conversion? Something like creating a Python object that points to the memory of the STL container...

Comment: I tried to find a way to avoid copies from STL to Python but couldn't find one.

Comment: @Rackbox You can avoid copying data using the buffer protocol. I don't know if std::vector has the buffer protocol already built, or if you have to do it yourself. But the pybind11 test scripts do tests for the buffer protocol so you should be able to look there for how to use it.